# How do I fix the TypeError for ufunc 'isfinite'?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Traceback is below. I'm not entirely sure what this means about the error and where I have to fix it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/william/SOFTX-D-16-00075-master/runGsolve.py", line 1775, in <module>
    dmw = DesignerMainWindow()
  File "/home/william/SOFTX-D-16-00075-master/runGsolve.py", line 45, in __init__
    self.setupUi(self)
  File "/home/william/SOFTX-D-16-00075-master/GsolveGUIv3.py", line 410, in setupUi
    self.mplwidget = MatplotlibWidget(self.frame_14)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyqtgraph/widgets/MatplotlibWidget.py", line 34, in __init__
    self.fig = Figure(size, dpi=dpi)
  File "/home/william/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 348, in __init__
    if not np.isfinite(figsize).all():
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

The code for line 348 in that last call is from matplotlib and is as follows..

```
        if not np.isfinite(figsize).all():
            raise ValueError('figure size must be finite not '
                             '{}'.format(figsize))
        self.bbox_inches = Bbox.from_bounds(0, 0, *figsize)
```

Comment: What is `self.frame_14`, and why are you passing it to `MatplotlibWidget`? Have you checked the [documentation](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/widgets/matplotlibwidget.html) for what arguments `MatplotlibWidget` takes?

Comment: I'm trying to open up this programe (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2352711018300566), with code found here (https://github.com/ElsevierSoftwareX/SOFTX-D-16-00075)

All I'm doing is trying to run that.

Comment: You seem to have the wrong `MatplotlibWidget`; you're using the version from `pyqtgraph.widgets`, rather than the one provided in the repository you're looking at. It doesn't seem possible for something like this to happen unless you made a bad edit to `GsolveGUIv3.py`.

Comment: That said, there's no `matplotlibwidget.py` in the repository, only a `matplotlibwidget.pyc`, so it's hard to say what might be going on in that file. Also, you'll likely need to use *exactly* the Python version this code was developed on.

Comment: Yeah I'm not using the exact Python version so I think that is the issue. I've had to update from PyQt4 to PyQt5 as well.